# Turn a date text string into date in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets, formula

I need to turn the string below into a date for comparison
April 30, 20181:00 PM - 1:45 PM PT

I used =SPLIT(C2,"8") to separate the time, but looking for a regex that could maybe do the conversion in one go perhaps with =DATEVALUE(C2)

Comment: What is your expected output? For `April 30, 2018, 1:00 PM` should you get something like `04-30-2018-1300` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently a date range, which is not going to work

Drop everything after the first PM, using split, and then `DATEVALUE(C2)` will work.  Also, there is a space missing after 2018

Comment: The date text string comes down the pipes without a space, but I'll give your suggestion a go and manually edit one for now